# what is the best way to remove words from richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

***strong text***I have a richTextBox and like to search the line of sentence that starts with Hello Worlds and Contains "HERE". and end with ; semi-column than I like to delete only* "HERE".  *. My sentence, below example is only one line of sentence, but sentence may be 2 lines long, so condition should be start with  Hello Worlds and ends with ; semi-column than remove* "HERE".*

***my one line of sentence:***

```
Hello Worlds the weather is too hot "HERE"."IN" CANADA!;
```

***my 2 lines of sentence might be this:***

```
Hello Worlds the weather is too hot "HERE"."IN" CANADA!. But we are still like it;
```

***result should be for one line:***

```
 Hello Worlds the weather is too hot "IN" CANADA!;
```

***result should be for 2 lines:***

```
Hello Worlds the weather is too hot "IN" CANADA!. But we are still like it;
```

well I stuck on my code:

```
                   List<string> rt = new List<string>();
                        foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
                        {
                            if (line.StartsWith("Hello Worlds") && line.Contains("HERE"))
                            {
                               //remove "HERE".
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

```
string[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
List<string> linesToAdd = new List<string>();
string filterString = "\"HERE\".";
foreach (string s in lines)
{
    string temp = s;
    if (s.StartsWith("Hello Worlds") && s.EndsWith(";") && s.Contains(filterString))
       temp = s.Replace(filterString, string.Empty);
    linesToAdd.Add(temp);
 }
 richTextBox1.Lines = linesToAdd.ToArray();
```

Comment: error at ("HERE")   cannot convert from 'string' to 'int' . it sees like string.Remove(int)

Comment: I like to remove "HERE".

Comment: new error at s =   : Cannot assign to 's' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Comment: updated........ Tested this time

Comment: @user2661591 is your problem resolved?

Comment: Close now seeing the result :  Hello Worlds the weather is too hot ""."IN" CANADA!;

Comment: result should be: Hello Worlds the weather is too hot "IN" CANADA!;

Comment: you mean double quotes are not removed?

Comment: updated my code to handle that

Comment: I have dot too after "HERE".

Comment: well that wasn't difficult, just add it in the filter string. i have added that in my code.

Comment: one last thing. can I add textbox inside to string filterString = "\"HERE\"."; make it dynamically to delete the any word that start with    Hello Worlds and end with ; ?

Comment: like string filterString = "\"textBox1\".";

Comment: yes you can do it like this string filterString = "\""+ textBox1.Text +"\".";

Comment: I like to use your code for other lines that has similar condition. only differents is "HERE".

Comment: I used this : string filterString = "\"" + txtBox.Text + "\".";  but no luck

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35937/discussion-between-no-one-and-user2661591)