# How to delete all match and delete text

Tags: c#, richtextbox

How can I delete words from a "string" in the `RichTextBox`.

Example:

```
[02/04/2014 17:04:21] Thread 1 Banned: xxxxxxxxx@xxxx.tld 
[02/04/2014 17:04:21] Thread 2: Banned: xxxxxxxxx@xxxx.tld 
[02/04/2014 17:04:21] Thread 3: Banned: xxxxxxxxx@xxxx.tld 
[02/04/2014 17:04:21] Thread 4: Banned: xxxxxxxxx@xxxx.tld
```

I would like to delete all rows with the word "Banned" in the line.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using RegEx and captures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ to remove all the lines that contains the work "Banned":

```
richTextBox1.Lines = richTextBox1.Lines
    .Where((line, b) => !line.Contains("Banned"))
    .Select((line, b) => line).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try use the answer from this post - I would adjust the code slightly to neaten it up a bit.

URL: 
[what is the best way to remove words from richtextbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363308/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-words-from-richtextbox)

Code snippet from the URL (which would need to be tidied up).

```
string[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
List<string> linesToAdd = new List<string>();
string filterString = "Banned".";
foreach (string s in lines)
{
    string temp = s;
    if (s.Contains(filterString))
       temp = s.Replace(filterString, string.Empty);
    linesToAdd.Add(temp);
 }
 richTextBox1.Lines = linesToAdd.ToArray();
```

I would adjust the above code and whilst still using the loop, just check if the line contains the word you looking for "Banned" and then remove the line / do what is need with it.

I hope this helps?

Comment: @kpull1 This was not a complete solution, as I mentioned in the answer... He could use something like this but (and I say this) "The code would need to be edited"...

Comment: @kpull1 I have made the adjustment in the answer, regardless I still don't think it was worth a -1

Comment: @Syahmie That's great to hear, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I know this method looks ugly. But, if you don't want to remove formatting from the existing text in the richtextbox then you should use this method. This example is not tested but, you can get logic from here.

```
for (int iLine = 0; iLine < rtf.Lines.Length; iLine++)
{
    if (rtf.Lines[iLine].Contains("Banned"))
    {
        int iIndex = rtf.Text.IndexOf(rtf.Lines[iLine]);
        rtf.SelectionStart = iIndex;
        rtf.SelectionLength = rtf.Lines[iLine].Length;
        rtf.SelectedText = string.Empty;
        iLine--; //-- is beacause you are removing a line from the Lines array. 
    }
}
```

Comment: This was also work.. but i prefer to choose Guilherme.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: yes, Guilherme's solution is quite easy and faster.